# How can I stop a Ruin Guard's bayblade attack?

Tags: genshin-impact

Is there a way to stop this attack once the [Ruin Guard](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Ruin_Guard) has started it? I struggle sometimes with this attack, often in confined spaces, where it can just lay into my character.

[This is the attack I'm interested in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDvZU.jpg).

There doesn't seem to be a way to stop it once it begins.

The wiki has sparse tactics against this.

> The spinning attack is by far the most dangerous attack — not only
> does it deal high damage to anyone caught in its range, it also lasts
> very long, often killing the player in the process if they don't get
> out in time. If this happens, either disable the Ruin Guard if it
> isn't protected by its runes, or simply hit and run from a distance
> until they stop the attack; tanking it is unfeasible, even with
> high-durability shields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a short answer other the killing it during the attack, no there is no to stop the attack. You can however use shields to counter it intell the shield breaks. You can also temporarily negate it by using an ultimate. I have also found that Beidou's ability can block it while active.

Comment: Freezing enemy can also work in this situation

Comment: Yeah thing is most shields dont last long enough to last the whole beyblade, think even beidou's ult doesnt.

Comment: if you can somehow shoot an arrow at its weak spot during the attack, it stops as well
I used to have an Amos Amber until I got Ganyu, so I have stopped my share of spinning ruin guards

Answer (score 3):

Based on numbers alone, it seems that there is little hope to be able to break a ruin guard poise during its spinning attack- assuming that it is possible in the first place. They are considered boss-type, with a threshold of 2000 and a 100/s points recovery. So, I don't think you have any reliable means to stagger them to interrupt the spinning.

This leaves only one single option. Stunning the guard by hitting its weak point. It ***is*** possible to hit the guard in the eye while it is spinning, but it requires a good amount of skill/luck. Also, obviously if the guard currently has its shield ability active this won't work either.

Anyway, once you are caught in the attack there is nothing you can do reliably to get out. Sometime you may get lucky with some invulnerability frames granted by an elemental burst, sometime you may get out using small characters (Mona dash also seems to have strange properties here, but they are probably more related to its weird invulnerability frames than anything else) but most of the times you are already flying around like a ragdoll, get thrown into a wall and... can't do anything until you die.

That said, while this does not count as stopping the attack, it is still possible to create a geo construct (Geo-Traveler is the best option, Zhongli probably works but it is far harder to achieve) just at the right time under the guard and raise it above the ground. Most of the time this end up with the guard unable to climb down from the construct, completely unable to hit you. Furthermore, while I don't know if this still work, in previous versions a stunned guard on a geo construct was completely unable to return to its "regular" unstunned state.

Comment: _if the guard currently has its shield ability active_ - which shield ability?

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica after you stun a guard, it deploys a "shield" ability on its weak point and you can't stun it again for some seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I discovered an easy way to stop the ruin guard's spinning attack by accident. I main geo traveler (I know I know, everyone hates him in co-op but his elemental skill has so much amazing utility!) and I found that if I summon a boulder underneath the ruin guard as he's spinning, he'll be unable to move and be stuck spinning on the boulder.

This often buys me enough time to take out other enemies in the area or pop a heal with Bennett's elemental burst!

Also for a really easy way to stun the ruin guard without an archer... When the ruin guard jumps towards you, he'll temporarily lower his head to ground level. If you have some sort of shield you'll be able to resist the knockback and attack his face with melee which will stun him.

My favorite way to counter and stun a jumping ruin guard this way is by using Beidou's elemental skill because I'll receive 0 damage and inflict so much more. It takes a little practice to time it perfectly but is totally worth it. Super satisfying when you pull it off, trust me!

Comment: Even better: unless they fixed it, a stunned ruin guard on a boulder is unable to exit the stun status.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but I find that when battling a single ruin guard, if you keep up the attack, sprinting quicky away from punches and such and then immediately reingaging, the ruin guard will never do its spinning blade attack or fire its missiles.

That doesn't explain how to stop the ruin guard's attack, but it does explain how to *avoid* it.

I never worry about trying to hit the weak point; I just keep slashing at it until it's dead.

Comment: The missile fire is really a 'you are far away' attack. When i'm stuck fighting multiples I prefer just putting them in a bunch and pumping damage into it.